# How to insert values in junction table for many to many relationships?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-theory, rdbms

I have three tables in database:

```
 trips(trip_id(pk), trip_name(unique), user_id(fk))

 places(place_id(pk), place_name(unique))

 trips_places_asc(trip_id(fk), place_id(fk))
```

Since many trips can have many places, I have one junction table as above.

If a user inserts places to the trip, the places will be added to `places` table and the trip will be associated with the places in `trips_places_asc` table.

So, if I write  a query like:

```
INSERT INTO places (place_name)
VALUES ('XYZ')

INSERT INTO trips (trip_name)
VALUES ('MyTrip')
```

then how to store `trip_id` and `place_id` in Junction or Association table `trips_places_asc`? Will I have to fire two queries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to maintain **atomicity** of the action of storing a new place and trip, along with the intersection between the two.  In MySQL, you do this with a `START TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT` transactional wrapper.

You use the MySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (See [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id); similar to SQL Server variable `@@IDENTITY`) to get the value of the most recent auto increment value assigned.

To add a *place* and a *trip* and associate the two all at once, you would write code like this:

```
START TRANSACTION

DECLARE placeKey int

INSERT INTO places (place_name)
VALUES ('XYZ')

SET placeKey = LAST_INSERT_ID()

DECLARE tripKey int

INSERT INTO trips (trip_name)
VALUES ('MyTrip')

SET tripKey = LAST_INSERT_ID()

INSERT INTO trips_places_asc(trip_id, place_id)
VALUES (tripKey, placeKey)

COMMIT
```

You should add error handling to the above and if an error occurs part way through, use the `ROLLBACK` command to undo the partially completed work.

You should also read up on LAST_INSERT_ID() to make sure you know how it works.  It can give you undesirable results in some cases, such as when you insert multiple rows with a single insert statement.

Comment: I heard that transactions are implicit in MySql. Do I need to use explicit transactions for each query or just for concurrent processes?

Comment: @xyz  Having implicit `COMMIT` is not the same thing as never having or wanting to control you transaction scope.  When you are writing into multiple tables in a single logical unit of work you will want to control your transactions explicitly

Comment: @JoelBrown will you please say what is @@IDENTITY and how it's comes

Comment: @siddhesh - [@@IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) is SQL Server.  I have corrected this answer to reflect MySQL, which is one of the OP's tags.  The MySQL equivalent of @@IDENTITY is [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Comment: What would be the best way to manage this if we were inserting a huge amount of records ? In Postgres or MSSQL, I would have to use something like PL/PGSQL or MSSQL equvivalent ?

Comment: @theMyth This works for one record/set of records at a time because there are functions which capture auto increment (identity) values in a script as part of a transaction. There aren't functions that can get sets of these auto increment values (even small ones, never mind huge ones). You can wrap huge sets of individual inserts into a single transaction to ensure atomicity, although very large transactions have their own practical limitations and challenges. You could also consider a batched approach where you prescribe the ids and then use a tool like SQL BCP to load huge data sets.

Answer (score -1):

```
     ---Method 1 using Ident_Current 

  BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO places (place_name)
        VALUES ('XYZ')

        INSERT INTO trips (trip_name)
        VALUES ('MyTrip')

        Insert INTO trips_places_asc (trip_id,place_id) values
        (Ident_Current('trips'), Ident_Current('places'))

   COMMIT TRAN
      ---Method 2 Using Scope_Identity 

        Declare @PlaceId int ,   @tripid int
        INSERT INTO places (place_name)
        VALUES ('XYZ')
        set @PlaceId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        INSERT INTO trips (trip_name)
        VALUES ('MyTrip')
        set @tripid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        Insert INTO trips_places_asc (trip_id,place_id) values
        (@tripid, @PlaceId)
```

Comment: the question is about MySQL. Not about SQL-Server. And you are missing several `;`